# error de la libreria: tcpdf Some data has already been output, can't send PDF file

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, tcpdf

Estoy teniendo un error en mi codigo

```
<?php

require_once "../../controllers/gestorsuscriptores.php";
require_once "../../models/gestorsuscriptores.php";

require_once('tcpdf_include.php');

$pdf = new TCPDF(PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION, PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, true, 'UTF-8', false);

$pdf->AddPage();

$html = <<<EOF

  <img src="images/logo_example.jpg" style="width:300px">
EOF;

$pdf->writeHTML($html, false, false, false, false, '');

$pdf->Output('pdf.pdf', 'I');

?>
```

el problema que encuetro es que cuando escribo el codigo

```
require_once "../../controllers/gestorsuscriptores.php";
require_once "../../models/gestorsuscriptores.php";
```

me da el error de: **TCPDF ERROR: Some data has already been output, can't send PDF file**

LOS ARCHIVOS LOS TENGO EN LAS CARPETAS, DE ESTA MANERA

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

CUANDO ESCRIBO LA PRIMERA LINEA DE CODIGO NO ME DA NINGUN ERROR

```
require_once "../../controllers/gestorsuscriptores.php";
```

PERO AL ESCRIBIR LA SEGUNDO, ES DONDE SALTA EL ERROR

```
require_once "../../models/gestorsuscriptores.php";
```

**TCPDF ERROR: Some data has already been output, can't send PDF file**

Y SI SOLO ESCRIBO EL SEGUNDO CODIGO SIN EL PRIMERO TAMBIEN VUELVE A DAR ERROR

EL CODIGO DEL ARCHIVO gestorsuscriptores.php ES ESTE:

```
<?php 
require_once 'conexion.php'; 
class SuscriptoresModel
{
    #MOSTRAR SUSCRIPTORES EN LA VISTA
    #------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    public function mostrarSuscriptoresModel($tabla)
    {
        $stmt = Conexion::conectar()->prepare("SELECT id, nombre, email FROM $tabla");
        $stmt -> execute();
        return $stmt -> fetchAll();
        $stmt -> close();
    }

    #BORRAR SUSCRIPTORES
    #------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    public function borrarSuscriptoresModel($datosModel,$tabla)
    {
        $stmt = Conexion::conectar()->prepare("DELETE FROM $tabla WHERE id = :id");
        $stmt->bindParam(":id", $datosModel, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        if ($stmt->execute()) 
        {
            return "ok";
        }
        else
        {
            return "error";
        }
        $stmt->close();
    }
}
```

REALMENTE NO SE QUE ESTARA PASANDO
ESPERO Y PUEDAN RESPONDER Y DE ANTEMANO MUCHISIMAS GRACIAS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

LOGRE SOLUCIONARLO CON EL SIGUIENTE CODIGO

```
ob_end_clean();
```

ESE CODIGO HAY QUE AGREGARLO ANTES DE:

```
$pdf->Output('pdf.pdf', 'I');
```

EL CUAL LO ENCONTRE EN:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/35951509/10222790

SIRVE PARA:  Limpiar (eliminar) el búfer de salida y deshabilitar el almacenamiento en el mismo

http://php.net/manual/es/function.ob-end-clean.php